# Non-EU citizen in Germany being offered a role in Series

Tags: germany, citizenship, working, dependent-visa, switzerland

I am currently living in Germany on family reunion visa and have been offered a part time role in Switzerland. Would taking this role stop my citizenship countdown for Germany ?

Thanks

Comment: Without any information as to how long you would be outside of Germany, this cannot be answered. The general rule is **after 6 months absence** then an *Interruption of habitual residence* has taken place.

Comment: NB: Many people live in Germany and commute to Switzerland. If the role is in northern Switzerland, you might want to investigate this alternative.